# Filter applause from videos

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I am currently watching a video from 27C3 and I would like to filter the applause, as it is very loud. Is this possible? I have heard something like this was made for Vuvuzelas.

I use Ubuntu. If this filter would work via ffmpeg this would be great. If it is written in Python it would also be ok.

Here is an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIViQuCX7XM#t=5m4s

Comment: You might want to ask this question on http://audio.stackexchange.com, too.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know that StackExchange-Site. Should I ask the question there again or can I "move" this question from StackOverflow to audio?

Comment: I think it can't be moved directly, so you need to ask it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  The sound of applause covers a very wide band.  Filtering vuvuzelas was somewhat possible because they were all close to the same pitch.  Applause is all over.

If you want to experiment, pull up this video and play with your EQ in VLC.  Even with the wide bands of a 7-band EQ, you'll be dropping quite a few to cut the audience, thus leaving you with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic range compressor, this will not filter out the applause, but at least it will smooth out the loudness. You can give it a threshold so that it doesn't affect sound below that threshold.

Comment: The only thing normalization does is set the maximum level of audio to a certain level (usually just under 0dB), uniformly increasing everything.  This will do nothing to fix the problem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_normalization

Comment: Yes, but the question suggests that the loudness of the applause is a problem. In this case normalization will help.

Comment: I don't think so. You probably mean a compressor.

Comment: In VLC I can set a normalizer by "Settings -> Preferences; Tick Advanced Options in the bottom right corner; Then go to Audio -> Filters -> Volume Normalizer"; mp3gain/gnormalize for audio-files. I knew this, but I wanted to mute the applause completely while other sounds can be heard. This didn't answer my question, but it is useful.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with Audacitys' function for removing noise. It works fine for the sounds of many people talking in the background.

Comment: It doesn't work with applause. The best results can be achieved by setting 10dB, frequency to 1000 Hz and time as high as possible in audacitys noise reduction function.

Answer (score 1):

As Brad said, this is not possible with a static frequency filter, however, if you have some knowledge in signal theory, and a fair lot of free time, you could write an [active noise control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control). See google scholar for some examples of such a filter ([like this one](http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2000/SESSIONS/THUPM/PO3/CR1407.PDF)).